Mode Clustering ,Wildfly 21 , One node out of 2 nodes suddenly gets down
I am using Spring MVC 5, java 11, mod_cluster/1.3.16. Final. Suddenly 1 node fails out of 2  and the below exception prints on the server console. I am out of solution and need help.

2024-06-19 02:22:08,245 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER]
(thread-57,ejb,jvm1) ISPN100001: Node jvm3 left the cluster 2024-06-19
02:22:08,245 INFO  [org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan] (default
task-21) WFLYCLEEINF0001: Failed to cancel
WRQ0WOd-ioxzBQV6kiyhumj2RQBcyM73Wxyr05Wf on primary owner.:
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
at org.wildfly.clustering.server@21.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.clustering.server.dispatcher.ServiceRequest.completeExceptionally(ServiceRequest.java:86)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.blocks.UnicastRequest.viewChange(UnicastRequest.java:78)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.lambda$receiveView$1(RequestCorrelator.java:281)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3605)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveView(RequestCorrelator.java:281)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:228)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:569)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:765)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:911)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FORK.up(FORK.java:132)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG3.up(FRAG3.java:151)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FlowControl.up(FlowControl.java:338)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.installView(GMS.java:707)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.ServerGmsImpl.handleViewChange(ServerGmsImpl.java:65)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.ParticipantGmsImpl.handleViewChange(ParticipantGmsImpl.java:113)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:922)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:330)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:297)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:450)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.deliverBatch(NAKACK2.java:952)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.removeAndDeliver(NAKACK2.java:886)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.handleMessages(NAKACK2.java:860)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:682)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:338)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.FailureDetection.up(FailureDetection.java:197)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:338)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:338)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:338)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.stack.Protocol.up(Protocol.java:338)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passBatchUp(TP.java:1411)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.util.MaxOneThreadPerSender$BatchHandlerLoop.passBatchUp(MaxOneThreadPerSender.java:284)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.util.SubmitToThreadPool$BatchHandler.run(SubmitToThreadPool.java:136)
at org.jgroups@4.2.5.Final//org.jgroups.util.MaxOneThreadPerSender$BatchHandlerLoop.run(MaxOneThreadPerSender.java:273)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextReferenceExecutor.execute(ContextReferenceExecutor.java:49)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.common@21.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.clustering.context.ContextualExecutor$1.run(ContextualExecutor.java:70)
at java. base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

2 - web.xml contains <distributable/> tag
3- The Widlfy 21 standalone configuration is below.
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:11.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="routing" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="sso">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </replicated-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="routing"/>
                <distributed-cache name="dist">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="routing" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="routing"/>
                <distributed-cache name="dist">
                    <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <file-store/>
                </distributed-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="server" aliases="singleton cluster" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="default">
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </replicated-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <heap-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="pending-puts">
                    <expiration max-idle="60000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <invalidation-cache name="entity">
                    <heap-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </invalidation-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="timestamps"/>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
<stack name="tcp">
                    <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                    <socket-protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
                    <protocol type="org.jgroups.protocols.TCPPING">
                        <property name="initial_hosts">10.20.30.101[7600],10.20.30.107[7600]</property>
                        <property name="port_range">0</property>
                    </protocol>
                    <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                    <socket-protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_ALL"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG3"/>
                </stack>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:5.0">
            <proxy name="default" advertise="true" advertise-security-key="######" advertise-socket="modcluster" balancer="cslt1" listener="ajp" node-timeout="120" sticky-session="true">
                <dynamic-load-provider>
                    <load-metric type="busyness"/>
                </dynamic-load-provider>
            </proxy>
        </subsystem>

4 - Apache configuration is below.
<VirtualHost 10.20.30.80:9080>
    
    <Directory />
        Require ip 10.20.30.101
        Require ip 10.20.30.107
    </Directory>
    
    ServerAdvertise On
    AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23367
    EnableMCPMReceive on
    ManagerBalancerName cslt1
    AdvertiseSecurityKey ######
    
 
   <Location /mod_cluster-manager>
   SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
   #Require ip 10.20.30.80
  </Location>
  
 </VirtualHost>

